# SQLAlchemy way to filter an instance property

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have `User` and `Expense` classes. A single user has a list of expenses. I'd like to add a property `current_expenses` which returns only the list of expenses that are in the current month. Obviously, I can do:

```
class User(db.Model):

    ...

    def current_expenses():
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        db.session.query(Expense)\
            .filter(User.name = self.name)\
            .filter(db.extract('year', Expense.date_time) == now.year)\
            .filter(db.extract('month', Expense.date_time) == now.month)
        ...
```

But this seems silly, since SQLAlchemy already has a list of expenses associated with the user instance. Is there a better way to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to conduct a query on the user's expenses, you can configure the relationship to be `dynamic`, which will return a query object for a users expenses.

```
class Expense(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'expense'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Integer)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    date_time = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    expenses = relationship("Expense", lazy='dynamic')

    @hybrid_property
    def current_expenses(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        ret = self.expenses.filter(extract('month', Expense.date_time) == now.month).all()

        return ret

e1 = Expense(amount=400)
e2 = Expense(amount=300)
u1 = User()
u1.expenses = [e1, e2]

session.add(u1)

print u1.current_expenses
```

Alternatively, if you use the default eager loading, you can just filter the Python list of expenses attached to the model instance.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    expenses = relationship("Expense")

    @hybrid_property
    def current_expenses(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        ret = [e for e in self.expenses if e.date_time.month == now.month]

        return ret
```